# Улица [название], дом 5-/—2

Tags: дефис-тире

Мне между числами ставить тире или дефис?

*Я живу по адресу: улица [название улицы], дом **5-/—2**.*

Имеется в виду *дом 5, квартира 2*. Такое сочетание можно писать сокращëнно: *5-/—2*. Но мне тире или дефис между числами поставить? По всем правилам нужно тире, но я в этом не уверен — случай всë-таки другой.

Comment: Максим, а зачем нужна такая запись, в чём её необходимость? Ни дефис, ни тире не дадут понять, что вторая цифра обозначает квартиру.  *5—2* будет воспринято как номер дома наподобие двойной нумерации *5/2*, или *дом 5, стр. 2*, или *дом 5 владение 2*, или *дом 5, корпус 2*. Не проще ли написать, как обычно: *д. 5, кв. 2*?

Comment: Я видел, что на бумагах так записывали. Первая цифра обозначает номер дома, а вторая — квартиру в этом доме. Так можно писать.

Comment: Тогда не нужно писать слово *дом*. Странно выглядит: одно пишем, а второе нет. Если их не писать, то, думаю, лучше (понятнее) через запятую: *улица Радости, 5, 2*.

Comment: Нет! Я видел на бумагах запись _дом 5-/—2_! Так и было, одно указывалось, а второе нет. Была именно такая запись. Не я это придумал.

Comment: Зачем так писать – вот вопрос. И смотря в каких бумагах. Свои принятые нормы записи могут быть разными в разных организациях. Если для всех понятно, то какая уже разница – дефис или тире, так как эту запись придумали с потолка, а не исходя из общепринятого обозначения. Адрес  – дело точное. А писать можно как угодно, главное, чтобы вас поняли. // К чему такие эмоции с воскл. знаками? Чувствуется раздражение. Я не собирался вас чем-то задеть. Спросил, в чём необходимость такой записи, непонятной без контекста, когда есть обычная и простая.

Comment: А я знаю, в чем необходимость? Увидел — вот и решил задать вопрос на форуме. Не надо мне ничего разъяснять, это не я написал, а другие люди приняли такое решение. Им и расскажи. А я на основе ЧУЖИХ записей задал вопрос.

Comment: Так если "не надо разъяснять", зачем спрашивать? Спросите у тех, ЧУЖИХ людей. Кажется, на ты не переходили. Да... что у вас с настроением? Почему в штыки воспринимаете? Я из лучших побуждений высказал своё мнение об этой записи.

Comment: Я просто доказывал, что не я виноват в этой записи. Извиняюсь за перехождение на ты, это случайно было. Давайте завершим этот разговор. Надеюсь, мы друг друга поняли.

Comment: Спасибо, вот это уже по-нашему. Разве я **вас** обвинял? Я хотел показать непонятность этой записи. Мы все здесь учимся, и учим наш язык всю жизнь. Приятно видеть новых активных участников на этом сайте. Успехов вам!

Comment: Если «по делу»... Тире оставьте для случаев 3 в 1 (Смоленский б-р, д. 6—8). Таких немного, но они есть: постройка 1967 г. уничтожила тогда три старых особняка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• В "Справочнике издателя и автора" А. Мильчина и Л. Чельцовой:

> [**6.1.7. Номера домов**](https://img.artlebedev.ru/izdal/spravochnik-izdatelya-i-avtora/Milchin-Numbers.pdf)
> Их принято писать без знака номера. Напр.: *Тверская, 13.* Особенностью отличается написание двойных и литерных номеров.
> **Двойные номера.** Их принято писать через косую черту: *ул. Пушкина,
> 15/18.*
> **Литерные номера.** Литеру принято писать слитно с последней цифрой
> номера: *Пушкинский пер., д. 27а.*

***В доме восемь дробь один**

У заставы Ильича

Жил высокий гражданин,

По прозванью Каланча...*
С. Михалков

• Интересные есть адреса, сложные — они нуждаются в особой записи:

***Славянская пл., д. 2/5/4, стр. 3*** (Москва) — третий слеш тут не подходит, поэтому строение оформляется отдельно;
***ул. Блохина, дом 5/2, литер А*** (Санкт-Петербург) — букву А к двойке присоединять нельзя, потому что она относится ко всему дому "5/2";
***Кутузовский проспект дом 7/4, корпус 1*** (Москва);
***Покровка, дом 3/7, стр. 1а*** (Москва).

• Запись адресов, про которую вы говорите, действительно **иногда** встречается (сама видела), но относится не к квартире, а к корпусу:
[*Дом **9-3** на улице Афанасьева*](https://foto.cheb.ru/foto/60340.htm) = улица Афанасьева, 9 корп. 3;
[*Санкт-Петербург, 24 линия ВО, **дом 3-7**, литера Б*](https://peregorodkitut.ru/obekt_4302_sankt-peterburg_24_liniya_vo_dom_3-7_litera_b).

О различении корпусов в справочнике ничего не сказано.
Думаю, что запись **дом 5-2** означает **дом 5, корпус 2**. И думаю, что она вполне возможна (но только с дефисом, так как тире предполагает значение "от... и до...").
Иногда также встречается такое обозначение: номер дома пишется крупно, а номер корпуса — помельче, через слеш (ул. Зелёная, 5/2; [см.](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005002313520460.html?sku_id=12000034632232076)).

А ещё это может быть частный дом на двух хозяев (в нашем городке таких — полно; например: *Jõe tänav, 18-1* и *Jõe tänav, 18-2*).
Или [рядный дом](http://vant.ee/2013/12/17/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B9%D1%8B%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%83%D1%83-%D1%83%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5-50/).